# File disappears, and re-appears

Tags: java, android, file, mode, objectinputstream

I have an android app in the store that saves some key-value-pairs in a file (see below). Recently I wanted to make a small update to the app (some fonts and colours, no logic) and I noticed that in the updated app the file was missing. I then uninstalled the app and installed the old version from the play store again and the data was there again. Why is the data missing in the updated version?

- The filename and path never changed.
- I did not change anything on those load/save methods
- The file must be somewhere because the old store app can still load it no matter how often I uninstall the app.
- In the updated version I changed the version code and the version number
- allowBackup="true" in the manifest is set
- compileSdkVersion is 25
- buildToolsVersion is 25.0.2
- minSdkVersion 9
- maxSdkVersion 25
- I have set the following permissions

  - INTERNET
  - WRITE_OWNER_DATA
  - ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  - ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

To save something to the file I use:

```
public void commit() {
    OutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        File file = mContext.getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectoutputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

        String json = new Gson().toJson(mAppsettings, AppSettings.class);
        objectoutputstream.writeObject(json);
        objectoutputstream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtils.v("Saving failed with IOException\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

To load the saved data I use the following:

```
private void load() {
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        File file = mContext.getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            mAppsettings = new AppSettings();
            return;
        }

        inputStream = mContext.openFileInput(FILENAME);
        ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        String json = (String) objectinputstream.readObject();
        mAppsettings = new Gson().fromJson(json, AppSettings.class);

        objectinputstream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtils.v("Settings: load(): IOException\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LogUtils.v("Settings: load(): ClassNotFoundException\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you store the file, i.e. what's the path?

Comment: `I noticed that in the updated app the file was missing.`. What do you mean? Apps (*.apk files) can only contain files in assets or raw resource. About which one are you talking>

Comment: @Henry the path from mContext.getFileStreamPath(FILENAME); is /data/user/0/com.medizinfuchs/files/myfile. So FILENAME=="myfile";

Comment: @greenapps 1st I have the store version installed and the file seems to be there (at the path above) because all data is visible. 2nd If I update the app with either a debug or a signed version of the update, all data is missing and in the logcat I can see that the file does not exist (file.exists==false). In older updates it always worked that the file was still there after the update. 3rd if I now uninstall the update and install the old version from the store again then all the data is there again.

Comment: So after the update a file in internal storage of your app who had been there before the update was missing? Is that all? Are the paths the same?

Comment: Further it is unclear if with the update you can write a file to internal storage of your app. And is so if you can then read it. You did tell nothing about this scenario.

Comment: @greenapps correct, a file in the internal storage of my app that had been there before the update is missing after the update. If I then uninstall the entire app and install the old store version, then the file is there again. Further I can write files with the updated version but this is not the point as I need to migrate the data of the old version.

Comment: You have not answered my questions. Does the posted code work with the new version was the question. And is that path different then?

Comment: unfortunately I can not definitely check the file path in the store app because there is no log. But I can say that I did not change anything about saving/loading the file. I thought maybe the android api under the hood may changed?! And yes, the posted code worked for several updates and also in the update it still works. Only the step from the previous the current update is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the

- compileSDKVersion from 25 -> 27
- minSdkVersion from 9 -> 14
- removed buildToolsVersion

and the problem does not occur anymore. I can't tell what exactly the problem was and why it is not a problem anymore. Thanks for all the help anyway!